# C# TCP client connect to server

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, networking, tcp

I am working on a Master - Slave kind of network relationship between a server and multiple clients.
The server is fine, the problem is that i am new to TCP and do not know how to connect to the server without the client knowing the ip form the start.

If someone could rewrite some of my code so it works, I would be thankful.

The server

```
namespace Server
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener listen = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8001);
        TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        int counter = 0;

        listen.Start();
        Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "Server Started");

        while (true)
        {
            counter += 1;
            clientSocket = listen.AcceptTcpClient();
            HandleClinet client = new HandleClinet();
            client.startClient(clientSocket, Convert.ToString(counter));
        }
    }
}

public class HandleClinet
{
    TcpClient clientSocket;
    string clNo;
    public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket, string clineNo)
    {
        clientSocket = inClientSocket;
        clNo = clineNo;
        Thread ClientThread = new Thread(DoChat);
        ClientThread.Start();
    }
    private void DoChat()
    {
        byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[1024];
        string dataFromClient = null;
        byte[] sendBytes = null;
        string serverResponse = null;

        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {
                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, 1024);
                dataFromClient = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("\0"));
                Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "From client-" + clNo + " " + dataFromClient);

                serverResponse = Console.ReadLine();
                sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
                networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);

                networkStream.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The client

```
namespace Client
{
class Program
{
    public static TcpClient tcpclnt = new TcpClient();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            LoopConnect();
            LoopPacket();
            tcpclnt.Close();
        }
    }

    private static void LoopPacket()
    {
        byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[1024];
        string dataFromClient = null;
        byte[] sendBytes = null;
        string serverResponse = null;

        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {
                NetworkStream networkStream = tcpclnt.GetStream();

                serverResponse = "Give me a command!";
                sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse);
                networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);

                networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, 1024);
                dataFromClient = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
                dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("\0"));
                Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "From server -" + dataFromClient);
                networkStream.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void LoopConnect()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                tcpclnt.Connect(IPAddress.Any, 8001); // The problem area
                break;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.Write(".");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Connected.");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Side note - your code has a serious issue - `Read` returns *the number of bytes that it placed in the buffer*. You've no guarantee, even if you ask for 1024 bytes and the other side has sent 1024 bytes or more, that it'll deliver 1024 bytes to you.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It is supposed to be a text application, the packets are not the problem here

Comment: We're not talking about packets here. **All** that TCP offers is an endless stream of bytes in both directions. If you want "messaging", it's up to *you* to implement that atop the endless stream of bytes or to move to a higher level protocol built on top of TCP that implements messaging (and maybe other things) for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client should somehow get address of the server. The method is depending on the network type (local or Internet). In case of Internet it's virtually impossible without some known peer. In case of a local network you could use a broadcast UDP request (this method is depending on the local network routing rules).

Comment: It is going to be a LAN only application. I could make it so that the host machine creates the client exe with the ip inside, than pass it on to everyone, but what happens if the router restarts and the addresses get mixed up? Is there maybe a way to loop through all ip addresses present on the network? (intended for home use, so should not be a problem)

Comment: @HegyAlpha - usually on a single well controlled network you'll a) assign static IP addresses to your servers and b) Have DNS available to assign *names* to which clients can bind rather than IP addresses (for b, if a isn't happening, it should be some form of dynamic DNS)

Comment: @HegyAlpha If this is LAN only then the approach with the UDP broadcast would be a preferable way. Although LAN routers should allow broadcast traffic. If your client and server will be inside of the same network segment, without any gates between them, then you should not have any issues at all.

Comment: @montonero Thank you, I will look into the UDP approach.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Since it's unknown what kind of server/client it will be then in general it can't rely on any names. I. e. these "servers" and "clients" could run on any machines within a network, not only on some dedicated server machine.